# When running command webpack I get an error Class extends value undefined is not a contructor or null at Object. Using webpack 4

Tags: webpack, webpack-4

I am using webpack 4 and finally get the cli part fixed from what I can tell, but now when I run `webpack` I get this error below.

Here is the stack trace:

```
TypeError: Class extends value undefined is not a constructor or null
    at Object.<anonymous> (/home/tbaustin/Turbo/portfolio/node_modules/webpack/lib/MainTemplate.js:33:45)
    at Module._compile (/home/tbaustin/Turbo/portfolio/node_modules/v8-compile-cache/v8-compile-cache.js:178:30)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (module.js:673:10)
    at Module.load (module.js:575:32)
    at tryModuleLoad (module.js:515:12)
    at Function.Module._load (module.js:507:3)
    at Module.require (module.js:606:17)
    at require (/home/tbaustin/Turbo/portfolio/node_modules/v8-compile-cache/v8-compile-cache.js:159:20)
    at Object.<anonymous> (/home/tbaustin/Turbo/portfolio/node_modules/webpack/lib/Compilation.js:21:22)
    at Module._compile (/home/tbaustin/Turbo/portfolio/node_modules/v8-compile-cache/v8-compile-cache.js:178:30)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (module.js:673:10)
    at Module.load (module.js:575:32)
    at tryModuleLoad (module.js:515:12)
    at Function.Module._load (module.js:507:3)
    at Module.require (module.js:606:17)
    at require (/home/tbaustin/Turbo/portfolio/node_modules/v8-compile-cache/v8-compile-cache.js:159:20)
    at Object.<anonymous> (/home/tbaustin/Turbo/portfolio/node_modules/webpack/lib/Compiler.js:16:21)
    at Module._compile (/home/tbaustin/Turbo/portfolio/node_modules/v8-compile-cache/v8-compile-cache.js:178:30)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (module.js:673:10)
    at Module.load (module.js:575:32)
    at tryModuleLoad (module.js:515:12)
    at Function.Module._load (module.js:507:3)
    at Module.require (module.js:606:17)
    at require (/home/tbaustin/Turbo/portfolio/node_modules/v8-compile-cache/v8-compile-cache.js:159:20)
    at Object.<anonymous> (/home/tbaustin/Turbo/portfolio/node_modules/webpack/lib/webpack.js:7:18)
    at Module._compile (/home/tbaustin/Turbo/portfolio/node_modules/v8-compile-cache/v8-compile-cache.js:178:30)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (module.js:673:10)
    at Module.load (module.js:575:32)
    at tryModuleLoad (module.js:515:12)
    at Function.Module._load (module.js:507:3)
```